# How to access custom exception class members when using catch(e)? And why exactly am I getting this error?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

How to access a custom exception class's member variable after we catch it in a catch argument?
And why exactly are we getting this error although the runtimeType shows that it is of type customException and not Object?

```
class CustomException implements Exception{
  //Custom Exception class
  String message;
  int numberMessage;
  CustomException(this.message, this.numberMessage);
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return message;
  }
}

void main() {
  try {
    throw CustomException('This is the best', 1223);
  } catch (z,t) {
      print(z);
      print(z.runtimeType); //Prints 'CustomException'
      print(z.numberMessage); //How do I access this member? Shows an error 'the getter 
                              //...numberMessage isn't defined for class Object'. 
      print(t.runtimeType);//Prints _StackTrace
  }
}
```

I tried adding the type as CustomException in the catch keyword like so, but even this didn't work as it is a wrong syntax.

```
catch(CustomException z, t)
```

Comment: You must use on keyword to catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is on keyword to catch particular type of exception in catch block, you can use that like below -

```
void main() {
  try {
    throw CustomException('This is the best', 1223);
  } on CustomException catch (z,t) {
      print(z);
      print(z.runtimeType); //Prints 'CustomException'
      print(z.numberMessage); //How do I access this member? Shows an error 'the getter 
                              //...numberMessage isn't defined for class Object'. 
      print(t.runtimeType);//Prints _StackTrace
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! But do you have any idea what is going on under the hood when I use catch only vs when I use 'on' to specify a particular type of exception? In both the cases, when I ask for runtimeType of 'z', it says 'CustomException' and not Object, although the error that appears when trying to access 'numberMessage' says that the runtimeType of 'z' is Object.